Recreating Louise Bourgeois' Insomnia Spirals (Fugue #12)
Louise Bourgeois
Louise Bourgeois (1911 - 2010) was a French-American artist. Although
she is best known for her large-scale sculptures, she was also a
prolific painter and drawer.

"The spiral is an attempt at controlling the chaos. It has two directions.
Where do you place yourself, at the periphery or at the
vortex?".
Louise Bourgeois
Her work has much in common with Surrealism. Many Surrealists, like
for example Man Ray, liked Mathematics, but Bourgeois actually
studied it. In 1930, she entered the Sorbonne to study mathematics
and geometry, subjects that she valued for their stability, saying "I got peace of mind, only through the study of rules nobody could
change."

Louise Bourgeois' famous Spider (tiny version)
Bourgeois graduated from the Sorbonne in 1935 and began studying art
in Paris. In 1938, she opened her own gallery where she showed the
work of artists such as Henri Matisse and Suzanne Valadon and where
she met American art professor Robert Goldwater as a customer. They
married and settled in New York City,  where she lived and worked for
the rest of her life. Bourgeois received her first retrospective in 1982, by the NYC Museum of Modern Art. Her work continues to be exhibited in museums and
public spaces around the world.

Louise Bourgeois, Spirals, 2005
Insomnia Drawings
During a protracted period of wakefulness - from November 1994 until June of 1995 - Bourgeois created 220 works on paper that were collated into a suite known as the "Insomnia Drawings." They oscillate between abstraction and figuration. She worked largely with her signature red and blue pens on cardboard or drawing paper - whatever was at hand in the middle of the night.

An image collage of some Insomnia Drawings
Fugue #12
In the years following her insomnia, Louise Bourgeois often returned to the motif of the spiral. I particularly like Fugue #12 - an arrangement of intertwined spirals superimposed in a complicated manner.

Louise Bourgeois, Fugue #12, 2003
My following recreation attempt shows how to create spirals with varying thicknesses and how to translate and rotate them. But I stopped after two spirals because I couldn't find a way to produce the interweaving (look at the top left spiral and its neighbour beneath).
Reproduction Attempt
Thickness variation
(based upon halirutan's answer to Vary the thickness of a plotted function)
points[{a_, b_}, c_] :=
 {f[a] - c[a]*g[a]/2, f[b] - c[b]*g[b]/2,
  f[b] + c[b]*g[b]/2, f[a] + c[a]*g[a]/2}

thickness := 0.75 (-Sin[2 #] + 2) &;

rmat := g[t_] = Normalize[RotationMatrix[Pi/2] . D[f[t], t]]

Resolution (smoothness of spiral)
r = 0.01;
resolution := Partition[Table[t, {t, 0, 6 Pi, r}], 2, 1];

Create and rotate spiral polygons
polys[d_] :=
 GeometricTransformation[
  Polygon /@ Map[points[#, thickness] &, resolution],
  RotationTransform[d Degree]]

First Spiral
f[t_] = {t Cos[t], t Sin[ t]};
rmat;
pa = polys[0];

Second Spiral
f[t_] = {20 + 0.75 t Cos[t], 2 + 0.5 t Sin[ t]};
rmat;
pb = polys[45];

Show graphics
Show[
 Graphics[{RGBColor[0.7, 0, 0, 0.9], #},
    Background -> RGBColor[0.7, 0.6, 0.3, 0.2]] & /@ {pa, pb}]


Question
Is it possible to reproduce Fugue #12 (at least approximately)?

Edit-2

Remove ConvexHullMesh, ConvexHullRegion or ConcaveHullMesh.
Work for early version for example 11.3;
There are some difficult about this problem.One of the difficult is that the parallel background lines must cover only by the red region, the second is that the random thickness. This answer solve the first one,the second maybe updated for last days.(The previous answer not so elegent)

Clear[spiralreg, regs, result];
spiralreg[center_ : {0, 0}, angle_ : 0, L_ : 30, 
   e_ : 2, ω_ : 3, thickness_ : .5] := 
  Module[{f, plot, lineout, linein, regout, regin, t0, linein2, 
    lineout2}, 
   f[t_] := 
    center + 
     RotationMatrix[angle] . {e*Cos[ω*t], Sin[ω*t]}*t;
   {τ[t_], ν[t_]} = 
    Last[FrenetSerretSystem[f[t], t]] // Simplify;
   lineout = Table[f[t] - thickness*ν@t, {t, 2, L, .01}];
   linein = Table[f[t] + thickness*ν@t, {t, 2, L, .01}];
   regout = 
    BoundaryMeshRegion[Join[Reverse@linein, lineout], 
     Line[Append[#, First@#] &@Range[Length@lineout + Length@linein]]];
   linein2 = Table[f[t] + 1.1  thickness*ν@t, {t, 2, L, .01}];
   lineout2 = 
    Table[f[t] - 1.1  thickness*ν@t, {t, 2, 
      L - (2  π)/ω, .01}];
   regin = 
    BoundaryMeshRegion[Join[Reverse@linein2, lineout2], 
     Line[Append[#, First@#] &@
       Range[Length@lineout2 + Length@linein2]]];
   {regout, regin}];
n = 40;
regs = spiralreg[#, RandomReal[{0, 2  π}], RandomReal[{10, 20}], 
     RandomReal[{1, 2}], RandomReal[{1, 4}], RandomReal[{.4, .5}]] & /@
    RandomSample[Tuples[{Range[-n, n, 20], Range[-n, n, 20]}]];
result = 
 Fold[RegionDifference[RegionUnion[#1, First@#2], Last@#2] &, 
  regs[[1, 1]], Rest@regs]


The result for  n=100;( Too slow in Version 14.0, but relatively faster in 11.3 or 12.2)

{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = RegionBounds[result];
Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[.2], 
  InfiniteLine[{0, #}, {1, 0}] & /@ 
   Flatten[Subdivide[ymin, ymax, 200][[#]] & /@ 
     Partition[Range[200], 5, 5][[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]], Red, result}, 
 PlotRange -> 100, Background -> RGBColor[0.7, 0.6, 0.3, 0.2]]


Edit-1

Now work for version >=12.2 and more spirals.
TODO: Update later for another idea,especially for the random thickness and does not depend on ConvexHullMesh.

spiral[center_ : {0, 0}, angle_ : 0, L_ : 10, e_ : 2, ω_ : 3, 
   thickness_ : .5] := Module[{f, τ, ν},
   f[t_] := 
    center + 
     RotationMatrix[angle] . {e*Cos[ω*t], Sin[ω*t]}*t;
   {τ, ν} = Last[FrenetSerretSystem[f[t], t]] // Simplify;
   Polygon[
    Join[Table[f[t] + thickness*ν, {t, 1, L, .01}], 
     Reverse@Table[f[t] - thickness*ν, {t, 1, L, .01}]]]];
regs1 = spiral[#, RandomReal[{0, 2 π}], RandomReal[{10, 20}], 
     RandomReal[{1, 2}], RandomReal[{1, 4}], RandomReal[{.4, .5}]] & /@
    RandomSample[Tuples[{Range[-40, 40, 20], Range[-40, 40, 20]}]];
regs2 = RegionDifference[BoundaryMeshRegion@*ConvexHullMesh@#, #] & /@
    regs1;
reg = Fold[RegionDifference[RegionUnion[#1, First@#2], Last@#2] &, 
  regs1[[1]], Rest@Thread[{regs1, regs2}]]


Original

Only a starting point. Take some ideas from my previous answer.
Needs the version >=13.3
We use ConvexHullRegion to get a large region which contain the spiral and use it to clip the previous spiral.

SeedRandom[1];
spiral[center_ : {0, 0}, angle_ : 0, L_ : 10, e_ : 2, ω_ : 3, 
   thickness_ : .2] := 
  RegionDilation[
   DiscretizeGraphics[
    ParametricPlot[
     center + 
      RotationMatrix[angle] . {e*Cos[ω*t], Sin[ω*t]}*
       t, {t, 0, L}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]], thickness];
regs = spiral[#, RandomReal[{0, 2 π}], RandomReal[{10, 20}], 
     RandomReal[{1, 2}], RandomReal[{1, 4}], .5] & /@ 
   RandomSample[Tuples[{Range[-20, 20, 20], Range[-20, 20, 20]}]];
reg = Fold[
  RegionDifference[
    RegionUnion[#1, BoundaryMeshRegion@*ConvexHullRegion@#2], 
    RegionDifference[BoundaryMeshRegion@*ConvexHullRegion@#2, #2]] &, 
  First@regs, Rest@regs]


{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = RegionBounds[reg];
Graphics[{AbsoluteThickness[.2], 
  InfiniteLine[{0, #}, {1, 0}] & /@ 
   Flatten[Subdivide[ymin, ymax, 200][[#]] & /@ 
     Partition[Range[200], 5, 5][[1 ;; -1 ;; 2]]], Red, reg}, 
 PlotRange -> 30, Background -> LightYellow]



Thank you, cvgmt, excellent

@eldo Thanks! But I am still not satisfied this answer, maybe I will get a new idea for some days.

spiral[] := Module[
  {n = 300, phi = RandomReal[{0, Pi}], a = RandomReal[{.7, .9}]
   , e = RandomReal[{1.2, 1.5}], x, y, z, t, points, thickness, img, mesh, mask},
  t = z = Subdivide[0, 15, n - 1];
  x = t Cos[a Pi t] + RandomReal[{.05, .07}, n];
  y = t Sin[-a Pi t] + RandomReal[{.05, .07}, n];
  
  points = RotationMatrix[phi, {0, 0, 1}].{{e, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}} . # & /@ 
   Transpose[{x, y, z}];
  thickness = RandomReal[{.1, .9}, n];
  
  img = Image@Graphics3D[{Directive[Black, Glow[Red]]
     , Tube[points, LowpassFilter[thickness, .55]]}
     , Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, 2}, ImageSize -> 500
     , ImagePadding -> 5, Background -> RGBColor[.96, .91, .85]];
  mesh = ImageMesh[Image[ColorNegate@Binarize@img, ImageSize -> 800]
     , Background -> Black, BaseStyle -> White ];
  mask = RegionImage[ConvexHullMesh@mesh, RasterSize -> 1400];
  ImageMultiply[mask, Rasterize[img, RasterSize -> 1400]] // 
     RemoveBackground[#, Black] & // ColorReplace[#, Black -> White] & // 
     Image[#, ImageResolution -> 600] &
  ]

SeedRandom[123];
Graphics[{
  Inset[spiral[], #] & /@ 
    RandomSample[Flatten[Array[6.5 {##} &, {4, 3}], 1]], 
  {Gray, Thin, Line[{{0, #}, {30, #}}]} & /@ 
    Flatten@Take[Partition[Range[ 1, 20, .1], 5], {1, -1, 2}]}
 , ImageSize -> 400, PlotRange -> {{5, 30}, {5, 20}}
 , Background -> RGBColor[.96, .91, .85]]  



Thanks, vindobona, a nice and interesting solution

Just another way to make a spiral.
spiral[a_, b_, n_, fi_ : 0] := 
 FilledCurve[
  BSplineCurve[
   Table[Evaluate[{a x Cos[x + Boole[fi == 0] Pi], -b Abs[x] Sin[
        x + Boole[fi == 0] Pi]}], {x, -n Pi, (n + 1) Pi, Pi/10}], 
   SplineClosed -> True]]

Graphics[{ColorData[97, 1], spiral[3, 2, 5], ColorData[97, 2], 
  spiral[3, 2, 5, 1]}]



